# copula omission in the comparative correlative construction

Tags: comparative-constructions, correlative-constructions

I was told the verb "be" (and its variants) can be omitted in the "the comparative..., the comparative..." construction. How about the following? Could the verb be omitted there?

> a. The more criminals there are, the more notorious a city **is**.

> b. The more criminals there are, the more notorious the city **is**.

Answer (score 1):

Without "is", both sentences are correct and they have the same meaning.

This structure is more natural when both parts have a verb or both parts don't, so it's more natural with "is" because the left part has a verb.

This structure is also more natural with "the" than "a", so b. is more natural than a.

Answer (score -1):

This particular one works because the verb is the same.  Consequently, it is implied in the second clause.  It works in

> The more criminals there are, the more notorious the city.

But it would not work for

> The more crimes are committed, the more notorious the city [are committed]

because that is nonsense.

Comment: Disagree. To me, the second sentence is also correct, and implies, "*The more crimes are committed **there**, the more notorious the city **is***." When the clauses are inverted, it's even clearer: "The more notorious the city, the more crimes are committed."